# Printing file name and line number of files matching a pattern

Tags: grep, find

I need to search the current directory and its sub-directories for regular files containing the words: "hello"

Why does this not work for me:

```
find . -type f | grep "hello"
```

Comment: `grep -Rn hello .`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pipe *find* into *xargs*, which will read correctly the results of *find*:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs grep "hello"
```

See the *xargs(1)* man page for more info.

Comment: You'll need `-0` for xargs to match that `-print0`, or to instead just use `find . -type f -exec grep "hello" {} +`

Answer (score 0):

With the command that you are proposing, you are looking for any filenames with the string `hello` in it RATHER than the string `hello` in the file contents. Use the below construct:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -n hello /dev/null {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can actually use `-regex` option of the `find` command.

```
find . -type f -regex ".*/.*hello.*"
```

`.*hello.*` -- matches names contains word "hello".
`.*/` is needed because `find` command returns the full path.